# Uber deep link on android

Tags: android, uber-api

I am unable to get Uber deep linking working on android. Here is my code.

```
pm.getPackageInfo("com.ubercab", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
                    Uri uberUri = new Uri.Builder().appendEncodedPath("uber://?action=setPickup&pickup=my_location")
//                            .appendQueryParameter("client_id",AppDriver.UBER_API_KEY)
//                            .appendQueryParameter("dropoff_latitude", beacon.getBeaconLatitude() + "")
//                            .appendQueryParameter("dropoff_longitude", beacon.getBeaconLongitude() + "")
//                            .appendQueryParameter("dropoff_nickname", beacon.getBeaconTitle())
                            .build();

                    Log.d("URI", uberUri.toString());

                    Intent uberIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uberUri);


                    List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(uberIntent, 0);
                    boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;

                    if(isIntentSafe) {
                        startActivity(uberIntent);
                    } else {
                        Log.d("DetailsFragment", "UBER INTENT WAS NOT SAFE");
                    }
```

I am trying to use the bare minimum query listed on the Uber Api Docs.

https://developer.uber.com/v1/deep-linking/

And I am getting no activity was found for the given intent. Am I setting up the intent wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of launching an intent on Android:

```
String url = "uber://?action=setPickup&pickup=94043";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```